# how can convert DataSet value to JSON Format in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, json.net

I have tried to converting like below code

```
public DataSet GetPreTaskId(int taskid)
{
    var da = itaskmanagerhi.GetPreTaskId(taskid);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        da, 
        Formatting.Indented, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });

    return json;
}
```

But this json value contain \n\r.

Comment: Why are you returning a Dataset from your service operation? This is bad. Bad bad bad. You should be returning a well defined DTO.

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting `Formatting.Indented` the result string becomes a "pretty-print" json, with new lines and tabs. Set to `Formatting.None` instead of this.

Example:

`Formatting.None` : `{ test: [1, 2, 3] }`

`Formatting.Indent`:

```
{
    test : [ 1, 2, 3]
}
```

or in pure representation: `{\r\n\ttest: [1, 2, 3]\r\n}`

More information about json formatting on the json.net site: [Formatting Enumeration](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_formatting.htm)

Comment: thank for replying me, i was tried "Formatting.Indent" but it is coming like {\r\n\test: [1, 2, 3]\r\n}